# Como modificar um objeto aninhado em React?

Tags: react

Estou tendo problemas para modificar as propriedades do address, da maneira que está só posso mudar o nome até o telefone, alguém poderia me dizer uma maneira de modificá-las?

```
 const dataInit = {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    cnpj: '',
    phone: '',
    address: {
      state: '',
      city: '',
      district: '',
      zip: '',
      obs: ''
    }
  }

  const [clinic, setClinic] = useState(dataInit);
  const onChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setClinic({...clinic, [name]: value });
  }

  const onSubmit = () => {
    const newClinic = {
      name: clinic.name,
      email: clinic.email,
      cnpj: clinic.cnpj,
      phone: clinic.phone,
      address: clinic.address
    }
    props.addClinic(newClinic);
  }
```

Comment: caso não tenha conseguido, faça uma mvp da sua pergunta no stackblitz ou sandbox code e nos manda o link. isso facilitará na resolução

Answer (score 0):

não seria assim ?

```
const onSubmit = () => {
    const newClinic = {
      name: clinic.name,
      email: clinic.email,
      cnpj: clinic.cnpj,
      phone: clinic.phone,
      address: {
       state: clinic.address.state,
        .... 
       }
    }
    props.addClinic(newClinic);
  }
```

Comment: Mas o problema é que dessa forma ele pega vazio(' '), a minha pergunta é sobre como editar o address, o onSubmit funciona, o problema o é a função onChange que nao consegue "entrar" no address para editar.